# given 1 chart in d3 fed by 1 file + want to draw X charts given an array of X files + d3

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js, svg

this is [my fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ygmkvreb/1/), which I am building on from this [example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3885304)

This is the main code to draw 1 chart. I am using an aray with 2 files for this example.

```
//array with 2 files(the same) just for example
arr = ["https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/49714666/data.tsv", "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/49714666/data.tsv"]

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
  .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
  .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

d3.tsv(arr[0], type, function(error, data) {
  if (error) throw error;

  x.domain(data.map(function(d) {
    return d.letter;
  }));
  y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) {
    return d.frequency;
  })]);

  svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "x axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(xAxis);

  svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "y axis")
    .call(yAxis)
    .append("text")
    .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
    .attr("y", 6)
    .attr("dy", ".71em")
    .style("text-anchor", "end")
    .text("Frequency");

  svg.selectAll(".bar")
    .data(data)
    .enter().append("rect")
    .attr("class", "bar")
    .attr("x", function(d) {
      return x(d.letter);
    })
    .attr("width", x.rangeBand())
    .attr("y", function(d) {
      return y(d.frequency);
    })
    .attr("height", function(d) {
      return height - y(d.frequency);
    });


  svg.selectAll(".barText")
    .data(data)
    .enter().append("text")
    .attr("class", "barText")
    .attr("x", function(d) {
      return x(d.letter);
    })
    .attr("y", function(d) {
      return y(d.frequency);
    })
    .text(function(d) {
      return d.frequency;
    });

});
```

Now if I want to add a 2nd chart I have to add the following code, and this works. Note I have to declare a new svg `svg2` and then append to this.
**edit** see the fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/HattrickNZ/ygmkvreb/8/)

```
var svg2 = d3.select("body").append("svg")
  .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
  .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

d3.tsv(arr[1], type, function(error, data) {
  if (error) throw error;

  x.domain(data.map(function(d) {
    return d.letter;
  }));
  y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) {
    return d.frequency;
  })]);

  svg2.append("g")
    .attr("class", "x axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(xAxis);

  svg2.append("g")
    .attr("class", "y axis")
    .call(yAxis)
    .append("text")
    .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
    .attr("y", 6)
    .attr("dy", ".71em")
    .style("text-anchor", "end")
    .text("Frequency");

  svg2.selectAll(".bar")
    .data(data)
    .enter().append("rect")
    .attr("class", "bar")
    .attr("x", function(d) {
      return x(d.letter);
    })
    .attr("width", x.rangeBand())
    .attr("y", function(d) {
      return y(d.frequency);
    })
    .attr("height", function(d) {
      return height - y(d.frequency);
    });


  svg2.selectAll(".barText")
    .data(data)
    .enter().append("text")
    .attr("class", "barText")
    .attr("x", function(d) {
      return x(d.letter);
    })
    .attr("y", function(d) {
      return y(d.frequency);
    })
    .text(function(d) {
      return d.frequency;
    });

});
```

Now this is not great practice as I am rewriting alot the same code.
But I want to be able to draw X charts giving an array of X elements of filenames. The files would have the same format.

**Can anyone advise, point me in the right direction, on how to do this?**

I have endeavoured to find a solution but I have come unstuck. 
I thought using a for loop, but I think the `d3.tsv` function is my issues as it is waiting for the data for the file, a callback?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the provided API for tsv files you can use the following:

```
d3.tsv(url[, accessor][, callback])
```

No accessor function:

```
endpoints.forEach(function(endpoint, index) {
    d3.tsv(endpoint, renderChart);
});
```

with optional accessor:

```
endpoints.forEach(function(endpoint, index) {
  d3.tsv(endpoint, type, renderChart);
});
```

Reuse your function or make a mapping to the function that correspond to each data endpoint. In this case I think your chart building fn is the same so you can do this.

```
function renderChart(error, data) {
   var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
  .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
  .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");
  // ..... rest of the code

}
```

Working jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ygmkvreb/11/

Comment: does that still use the type function?

Comment: @HattrickNZ the type function is just making sure that your value is of type number, it is always good to have those validations in order to avoid errors. In your case I think you are not using it. So you can remove it.

Comment: in this particular case I might not, but i think i am `d3.tsv("https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/49714666/data.tsv", type, function(error, data) {...`but given the way you have your code how would i use it? the below answer uses `type` function. tks

Comment: @HattrickNZ An optional accessor function may be specified as the second argument, let me update the answer

Comment: tk u v much, here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/HattrickNZ/ygmkvreb/15/) for my ref

Answer (score 2):

Adding into a for loop is the best way.  The thing you needed to do, was move the append svg call inside the loop:

```js
var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 40},
    width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var x = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .rangeRoundBands([0, width], .1);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([height, 0]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .orient("bottom");

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .orient("left")
    .ticks(10, "%");

var arr = ["https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/49714666/data.tsv","https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/49714666/data.tsv"]

for ( this_file in arr ) {
d3.tsv(arr[this_file], type, function(error, data) {
  if (error) throw error;

  x.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.letter; }));
  y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.frequency; })]);

 var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
  .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
  .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");
  
  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(xAxis);

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y axis")
      .call(yAxis)
    .append("text")
      .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
      .attr("y", 6)
      .attr("dy", ".71em")
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .text("Frequency");

  svg.selectAll(".bar")
      .data(data)
    .enter().append("rect")
      .attr("class", "bar")
      .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.letter); })
      .attr("width", x.rangeBand())
      .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.frequency); })
      .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.frequency); });
      
   
svg.selectAll(".barText")
      .data(data)                                 
      .enter().append("text")
      .attr("class", "barText")
      .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.letter); })
      .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.frequency); })
      .text(function(d) { return d.frequency; });
      
});

}

function type(d) {
  d.frequency = +d.frequency;
  return d;
}
```

```css
.bar {
  fill: steelblue;
}

.bar:hover {
  fill: brown;
}

.axis {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
}

.axis path,
.axis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.x.axis path {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: tks, here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/HattrickNZ/ygmkvreb/16/) but as a further question,i have added a chart title but it is the same title for each chart when I want it to be an element value per chart.